# Angular 4+ Creating a Semi-Circular Nav Menu, Modular vs. Global CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have been trying to create an animated circular navigation menu in Angular 4+ inspired by this [blog post](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/)

However I am having a little bit of trouble translating this into Angular properly. As a starting point I have stripped down the code to the absolute minimum working point. 1 html, 1 js and 1 css file.

This is the goal:

[image]

And this is what the following code produces right now. Notice the icons stuck on the left top corner driving the circular nav size to 0:

[image]

**Angular Code:**

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GuiltyGorillaMerch</title>
  <base href="/">


  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/modern.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/polyfills.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
          if (x.className === "topnav") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "topnav";
          }
      }

      myFunction()
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

bottom-menu.component.html

```
<button class="cn-button" (click)="handle()" id="cn-button">{{buttonLogo}}</button>
<div [ngClass] = "{'opened-nav': open}" class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-picture"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-headphones"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-facetime-video"></span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-envelope-alt"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div [ngClass] = "{'on-overlay': open}" id="cn-overlay" class="cn-overlay"></div>
```

bottom-menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bottom-menu',
  templateUrl: './bottom-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bottom-menu.component.css']
})
export class BottomMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  open : boolean;
  buttonLogo: string = "+";

  constructor() { 

    this.open = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

      var button = document.getElementById('cn-button');
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('cn-wrapper');
      var overlay = document.getElementById('cn-overlay');


  }

  openNav(){
    this.open = true;
    this.buttonLogo = "-"
  }

  closeNav(){
    this.open = false;
    this.buttonLogo = "+";
  }

  handle(){

    if(!this.open){
        this.openNav()
    }else{
        this.closeNav()
    }
  }
}
```

bottom-menu.component.css (directly copied from original CSS):

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css);

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f06060;
  color: #fff;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 26em;
  height: 26em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: -13em;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -13em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.cn-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cn-overlay.on-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cn-button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #f06060;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 3.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.75em;
  bottom: -1.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 11;
}

.cn-button:hover,
.cn-button:active,
.cn-button:focus {
  color: #aa1010;
}



.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  -webkit-transition: border .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: border .3s ease;
  transition: border .3s ease;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.18em;
  height: 14.5em;
  width: 14.5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  right: -7.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1.8em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(50deg);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) skew(50deg);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(70deg) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(70deg) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(70deg) skew(50deg)
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(110deg) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(110deg) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(110deg) skew(50deg);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) skew(50deg);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: #a11313;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 63%, 1);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(even) a {
  background-color: #a61414;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 65%, 1);
}


.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #b31515;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 70%, 1);
}



.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:focus {
  background-color: #b31515;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 70%, 1);
}
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:focus
{
    position:fixed;
}



.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: static;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6F325C;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 25.15em;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -12.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}


@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    font-size: .68em;
  }

  .cn-button {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    font-size: 1.52em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    width: 15.15px;
    margin-left: -7.5em;
  }

  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As soon as I moved the CSS to the global assets/styles.css
file the styling took effect properly. However I am curious as to why it works 
in global CSS but not in the module's respective css file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope

You define they styles for html, body etc. in a component that doesn't use those elements in its template, so those styles don't take effect, those need to be in your common styles file.

bottom-menu.component.css seems the right place for the css that only applies to the html you defined in your component, such as the .cn- classes

Comment: Hello Erik,
  Your answer turned out to be correct in an indirect way. I was aware of this property and apparently forgot to clean up those a few lines of CSS. The main reason for the bug turned out to be because the modernizer fall back script is not able to recognize the css in the module's css file which makes sense. I will look into properly refactoring the code